# A Java library to compress (e.g. LZW) a string

Tags: java, algorithm, compression, apache-commons, lzw

Apache Commons Compress works only with archive files (please correct me if I am wrong). I need something like

```
MyDB.put(LibIAmLookingFor.compress("My long string to store"));
String getBack = LibIAmLookingFor.decompress(MyDB.get()));
```

And LZW is just an example, could be anything similar.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a plethora of choices -

You can use the [java.util.Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) for the Deflate algortihm,

```
try {
  // Encode a String into bytes
  String inputString = "blahblahblah??";
  byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

  // Compress the bytes
  byte[] output = new byte[100];
  Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
  compresser.setInput(input);
  compresser.finish();
  int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);

  // Decompress the bytes
  Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
  decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
  byte[] result = new byte[100];
  int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
  decompresser.end();

  // Decode the bytes into a String
  String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
} catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
   // handle
} catch (java.util.zip.DataFormatException ex) {
   // handle
}
```

But you may prefer to use a streaming compressor, like gzip with a [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).

If you really want [LZW](http://code.google.com/p/lzwj/), there are [multiple](http://lzwcomp.sourceforge.net/) implementations [available](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15160/LZW-Compression-Algorithm-Implemented-in-Java).

If you need even better compression (at the cost of speed), you may want to use [bzip2](http://code.google.com/p/jbzip2/).

If you need even more speed (at the cost of compression), you may want to use [lzo](https://github.com/Karmasphere/lzo-java).

Comment: Has someone calculated how much Deflate algorithm implemented under java compress strings ?
Based on my testing the above code does not compress anything, byte[] result has the same byte size as the String inputString, and this is not expected behaviour

Answer (score 4):

Java has libraries built in for ZIP compression:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Will that do what you need?

Comment: (In particular, the Deflater streams which use [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE).)